# vscode auto suggestion does not include parameters for call to plsql procedure

Tags: visual-studio-code, autosuggest

The vscode auto suggestion is working in general, but does not fill in the parameter names between the brackets.
How can I get the auto suggestion to include this, so that I can make the call with named parameter values like this:

```sql
exec schema_name.package_name.procedure_name(arg1 => 'foo', arg2 => 'bar', arg3 => 'baz');
```

As I start typing the schema name it prompts me and I accept the suggestion with iether tab or enter.
Next I type a period and start typing the package name and it offers a suggestion which I accept.
Next I start typing the procedure name and it prompts me which I accept.
All of these suggestions have been offered in a hovering dropdown list below my cursor, each choice bulletted with a purple isometric cube.
[image: procedure dropdown suggestion]

Next I type an open bracket `(` and it shows the procedure definition in a different kind of hover box above my cursor, I can select the parameter names from there with my mouse and paste into my code, but I would prefer if the auto suggestion could have included them when I accepted the suggestion.
[image: procedure definition tooltip]